# Расчет стоимости хранения файлов для пользователя (AWS/S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Имеется сервис, который позволяет пользователю загружать файлы.
Для этого я использую AWS S3. Файлики каждого пользователя я кладу в отдельную "папку" (то-есть названия файлов одного пользователя имеют одинаковый префикс):

```
/user-id-1/file1.txt
/user-id-1/file2.txt
/user-id-2/file1.txt
```

Вопрос у меня следующий:
Как посчитать стоимость для каждого пользователя отдельно? То-есть мне нужно узнать сколько Gb в месяц лежит в "папке" `/user-id-1`

Что я пробовал:

- посмотреть это через CloudWatch (не получилось, так как инфу по размеру можно получить только по бакету целиком)
- получить список файлов и просуммировать размер (такой вариант мне не подходит, в случае если файлов много, допустим миллион, это будет очень медленно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Если достаточно расчёта раз в день.**
Использовать [AWS S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html). Эта опция ежедневно/еженедельно будет создавать листинг всех файлов (включая их размер) в формате CSV (ORC/Parquet по желанию) и класть его в какой-нибудь другой бакет. Дальше можно просто считатывать CSV и суммировать размер файлов. Теоретически можно создать несколько inventory для каждого префикса, т.е. для `/user-id-1` будет создан свой CSV-файл, а для `/user-id-2` -- свой.

Можно даже не парсить CSV/ORC/Parquet, а использовать AWS Athena для создания такого отчёта прямо из бакета с листингами.

**Если нужно считать занимаемое место в реальном времени.**
Придётся настроить [события S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). При каждом событии создания/удаления файла вызывать Lambda-функцию, которая будет добавлять/отнимать размер файла в базе данных.